# In graph theory, what's the difference of triangles and 3-faces?

Tags: planar-graphs

I'm pretty sure that triangles and 3-faces are not the same but I cannot find their differences according to their definitions. Could you please help me with that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In a planar graph the two notions are equivalent, but the notion of a triangle is more general: a $3$-clique (i.e., a copy of $K_3$) in **any** graph is a triangle, but the notion of *face* applies only to planar graphs.

Comment: Thanks. But I heard something like this: If a triangle has some other edges inside it's not 3-face. In other words, any 3-faces are triangles but all triangles are not 3-faces. Does it make sense?

Comment: @arny: In a planar graph a triangle can’t have any edges inside. If the vertices of the triangle are $u,v$, and $w$, any edge inside the triangle would have to have two of $u,v$ and $w$ as endpoints and would therefore just be one edge of the triangle.